# AngularFire after update throws ERROR FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ea', but it was: a custom Ta object

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm using AngularFire 7.4.1 with Angular 14.2.4 and RxFire 6.0.3

Since I'm updated angular from 12 to 15, AngularFire is throwing the following error:

```
ERROR FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ea', but it was: a custom Ta object
```

I'm importing everything from @angular/fire, including methods that are needed for module setup:

```
import { connectFirestoreEmulator, getFirestore, provideFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

... 
provideFirestore(() => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();
        if (!environment.production) {
            try {
                connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, "localhost", 8081);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }

        return firestore;
}),
...
```

The error is originating from this part of my code:

```
import { Firestore, doc, docData } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

foo() {
    return docData(doc(this.firestore, "metadata", "something")).pipe(
        map((data) => data?.stringArrayProperty ?? [])
    );
}
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out something was stuck among my node_modules, so running `rimraf -rf node_modules` and same for `package-lock.json`, then running `npm i` again solved the issue.